# $(hostname) keeps showing old hostname

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

After using this command:

```
ssh hostname echo"====$(hostname)===="
```

I keep getting the old hostname and not the new one. How do I get the new hostname?

Comment: In the string containing the `echo` command, `$(hostname)` is resolved before you ssh into the remote machine, so the remote machine just prints that precomputed string. Use single quotes to prevent that: `ssh hostname echo '====$(hostname)===='`

Comment: @pmf your suggestion worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command substitution in double quotes gets expanded by the shell before ssh gets the command. Use single quotes to prevent the expansion:

```
ssh hostname echo '====$(hostname)===='
# or
ssh hostname 'echo ====$(hostname)===='
```

Also note that the space after `echo` is not optional. I doubt the command produced any output without it.